# Finding a pair of vectors in $u$, $v$ in R that span the set of all x in R^4 that are mapped into the zero vector..

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find a pair of vectors in $u$, $v$ in $\mathbb R^4$ that span the set of all $x \in \mathbb R^4$ that are mapped into the zero vector by the transformation $x\rightarrow Ax$
>
> Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}1&3&-3&-4\\0&1&4&-3\\-3&-10&5&15\end{bmatrix}$

$u = \begin{bmatrix}\end{bmatrix}$ , $v = \begin{bmatrix}\end{bmatrix}$

Any tips or advice would be great. I'm not sure how to obtain my two $4 \times 1$ vectors $u$ and $v$

I put the matrix in RREF Form and got

$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&237/9\\0&1&0&-59/9\\0&0&1&8/9\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Try solving the associated set of simultaneous linear equations, or equivalently, row-reducing the matrix.

Comment: Should I put it in REF form or RREF?

Comment: RREF will make the solution set clearer.

Comment: Okay @DavidWheeler I got it in RREF form

Comment: Okay @DavidWheeler I got it in RREF form, see updated OP

Comment: Well, you did something wrong when computing the RREF, since what you have says that *no* vectors other than 0 get mapped to 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the question is asking to show find the kernel of the matrix $A$. I am under the assumption that $A$ is not an augmented matrix.

As finding the rref is a straightforward execution, I have shown it below

$A'=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&-15&5\\
0&1&4&-3\\
0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}$

Suppose $A'\vec{x}=0$ where $\vec{x}=\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
x_4
\end{bmatrix}$.

We have the free variables $x_3=s$ and $x_4=t$ and $x_2=-4s+3t$ and $x_1=15s-5t$.

Thus, any

$$\vec{u}=s\cdot\begin{bmatrix}
15\\
-4\\
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}:s\in\mathbb{R} \quad\!\!\text{and} \quad\!\!\vec{v}=t\cdot\begin{bmatrix}
-5\\
3\\
0\\
1
\end{bmatrix}:t\in\mathbb{R}$$

span the set of all vectors $\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R^4}$ such that $A\vec{x}=0$. In other words, $A\vec{x}=0 \quad \forall \quad\!\!\vec{x}=\vec{u}+\vec{v}$

Note that row reduction *does not* change the solution to the system of linear equations.

Comment: First of all, why does one of your matrices have ( ) and the other have [ ] . I never understood what the difference is? Second of all, How is your matrix in RREF when you don't have a 1 under the 4 ?

Comment: The brackets [] and parentheses () are just personal preferences. I tend to use brackets for row or column vectors and () for all else.

Comment: The definition of reduced row echelon form is that
1. It is in row echelon form
2. Every leading coefficient is $1$ and all other entries in that *column* are zeros.

Comment: So the last row has no "leading coefficient" correct?

Comment: That is correct. Also, when I found the rref, I did not consider $A$ as an augmented matrix as it would not make much sense to the problem.

Comment: How did you get 0 in the last row last column? I'm getting 16.

Comment: 1. add 3 times the 1st row to the 3rd row
--
2. add 1 times the 2nd row to the 3rd row
--
3. add -3 times the 2nd row to the 1st row